# Multivariate Linear Regression in Python

Tags: python, multivariate-regression

How to compute the overall standard error of a linear regression model using Python? Which library should I use? I am looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11479064/multivariate-linear-regression-in-python), however, I can't see how to get the overall standard error. Any ideas?

Comment: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html

Comment: Have tried this already but doesn't support multivariate... correct?

Comment: Ah, I see. How about http://www.datarobot.com/blog/multiple-regression-using-statsmodels/

Comment: Seems on the right path, however, I am not sure how to get the overall standard error... I can see on the std error of the individual variables. Any ideas?

Comment: Take the square root of `result.mse_resid`.

Comment: It's really not difficult to calculate on your own once you have the coefficients. I'd just do that.  I don't usually calculate the standard error of the regression anyway. The standard errors for individual variables are trickier (especially if you move away from standard assumptions of OLS).

Comment: ... assuming you're following [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14971531/3309177) (from the link you've provided) and you've saved it to an object named "result".

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have linear model Y = XB + e, for Y: n*q, X: n*p, B: p*q. 
Then:

```
def standard_error(X,Y):
    beta = inv(X.T.dot(X)).dot(X.T).dot(Y)
    return mean((Y-X.dot(beta))**2)
```